# Google App Engine app can not be authorized for Google Big Query server-to-server authorization

Tags: google-app-engine, authorization, google-bigquery

I am trying to authorize my Google App Engine (GAE) Java web application to use Google Big Query (GBQ) service. I have registered a Google business app and domain under xxxxxx.com and I created my GAE app logged in as user in my business space. Then I followed the instructions described here:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization

======================================

Using App Engine service accounts

The App Identity API provides a means for App Engine apps to identify themselves to Google for server to server API authorization. If you are creating an App Engine application, it's possible to authorize your application's service account to access Google APIs. Typical use cases include public data visualization or dashboard apps that do not require explicit user authorization before making calls to BigQuery.

To allow your App Engine app to make authorized service account calls to the BigQuery API:
Copy the App Engine service account name found under the Administration -> Application Settings tab (in the form of your_app_id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com).

Visit your Google APIs Console project's Team tab, and add the service account name as a project teammate with "Can edit" permissions

================================================

However, when I copy and paste my your_app_id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com as a teammate , I am greeted with: **Only users in domain xxxxxx.com may be added to the project**. Why is my GAE app not considered part of my domain, especially since when I go to the GAE admin console, it clearly shows I have created it being logged in as a member of my biz domain???

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same problem.

The workaround is to create a group email account (e.g. `bigquery@yourdomain.com`) on your Apps account and add `your_app_id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` as a member, then add the `bigquery@yourdomain.com` under the Team tab in BQ console.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I did the setup as you described it  and will test it shortly.

Comment: This really works! Is this documented anywhere? Not clear to me why an email alias works as a substitute for the service account, unless they specifically designed it that way.